# Error in Jenkins Openshift pipeline script about unable to read certificate-authority

Tags: jenkins, plugins, openshift

I have an Openshift simple test script, but I get an error, and I have no idea how to solve it. Someone said define `SKIP_TLS = true` in your Jenkins pipeline parametered definition will solve problem.

My script:

```
openshift.withCluster( "${KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST}", "${AUTH_TOKEN}") {
    openshift.withProject( "ph1" ) {
    def latestDeploymentVersion = 
    openshift.selector('dc','feign').object().status.latestVersion
    echo ${latestDeploymentVersion}
    }
}
```

I got error, I don’t know what I can do. How can I skip 
`--certificate-authority=/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt` in oc command?

> ERROR: Unable to retrieve object markup with get; action failed: {reference={}, err=error: unable to read certificate-authority /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt for console-appcanvas-net:8443 due to open /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt: The system cannot find the path specified., verb=get, cmd=oc --server=https://console.appcanvas.net:8443 --certificate-authority=/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt --namespace=ph1 --token=XXXXX get deploymentconfig/feign -o=json , out=, status=1}
>   Finished: FAILURE

Answer (score 2):

Replace **https to insecure** in KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST

Reference: https://github.com/jenkinsci/openshift-client-plugin/blob/master/src/readme/images/jenkins-online-help.png

Answer (score 0):

Just navigate to **Manage Jenkins -> Configure System** and scroll down to the OpenShift Client Plugin settings:

- Option A: add a valid **Server Certificate Authority** for your cluster. Which means a chain of certificates (Root, Intermediates, Server)
- Option B: Check **Disable TLS Verify** should also work (never tried though)

Answer (score 0):

Change the url protocol the following example:

from: **https**://cluster_url:port // (**https** should changed with **insecure**)

to:   **insecure**://cluster_url:port